# Every query I do regarding subscriptions returns different results

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to set up a webhook connecting contacts in my CRM with contacts on a users Outlook account using the subscription endpoint of the Microsoft Graph API. I have created some subscriptions, but when I try to get the list of them every time I get the response from the endpoint, it is a different list of them.

I want to start over my entire process of creation of the subscriptions, but I cannot get back to baseline because these subscriptions already exist. I cannot access them correctly due to there being a different list of them each request. This is the current function I am running to contact the subscription endpoint.

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.azureAuthResource.getAccessToken(accessToken => {
        const header = {
          headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken }
        };
        this.client.get(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions?top=10000`, header, data => {
          data = JSON.parse(data.toString());
          console.log('got subscriptions');
          resolve(data);
        });
      });
    });
```

This is an example of one of the subscriptions I am receiving back

```
changeType: "updated"
clientState: null
creatorId: "7e47df1e-7f11-45ca-a89a-d63dc83fdfa6"
expirationDateTime: "2019-04-05T17:43:36.449Z"
id: "ca39cff3-6f8a-49c2-aa84-c3777889ffeb"
notificationUrl: "https://us-central1-batteries-fb.cloudfunctions.net/graphContactSubscription"
resource: "users/sknopp@retrievtech.com/contacts"
```

but each time I run the mentioned function, the list of subscriptions I get back is vastly different. One request might give me 7 subscriptions, after a few second wait, I run the function again and receive 300, the next might return 800. I've looped through the larger responses, and there is some duplicates of resource, but the Id's are different between the duplicates.Can someone please explain to me why this might be happening?

Comment: Is it possible that you have a background process that's running and keeps registering new subscriptions?